# Crackmes challenge not validating all answers

Tags: assembly, c, ghidra, crackme

I am playing with [this](https://crackmes.one/crackme/62327b0433c5d46c8bcc0335) crackme. The executable takes a numerical input (e.g., 123) and adds all the numbers. The total must be 50. However, I noticed that not all inputs adding up to 50 are validated. For example: 5555555555 is validated, but 9191919191 is not.

Lines of interest: 20-28.

I am probably missing something, but I cannot figure out what it may be. Any ideas?

[image: Assembly and Seudo-C in Ghidra]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a problem with the binary - maybe intended. The `sum` variable is next to the char that is passed to `atoi` via a reference

```
int atoi(const char *nptr);
```

`atoi` expects a null terminated string while here in this case it gets pointer to a char that has an integer next to it - which might not have `\0` in your case and it would lead to problems.

for 5555555555 the argument to atoi in order would be - shown as qword here for clarity

```
0x0000000000000035 - "5\x00"
0x0000000000000535 - "5\x05\x00"
0x0000000000000a35 - "5\n\x00"
0x0000000000000f35 - "5\x0f\x00"
0x0000000000001435 - "5\x14\x00"
0x0000000000001935 - "5\x19\x00"
0x0000000000001e35 - "5\x1e\x00"
0x0000000000002335 - "5#\x00"
0x0000000000002835 - "5(\x00"
0x0000000000002d35 - "5-\x00"
```

Now these cases are handled well by `atoi` but in case of 9191919191

```
0x0000000000000039 - "9\x00\x00"
0x0000000000000931 - "1\t\x00"
0x0000000000000a39 - "9\n\x00"
0x0000000000001331 - "1\x13\x00"
0x0000000000001439 - "9\x14\x00"
0x0000000000001d31 - "1\x1d\x00"
0x0000000000001e39 - "9\x1e\x00"
0x0000000000002731 - "1"\x00"
0x0000000000002839 - "9(\x00"
0x0000000000003131 - "11\x00"
```

As you can see the last arg here is "11" which would mean 11 is added to `sum` hereby taking it to 60 instead of 50.

This can be verified

```
$ gdb -q ./license_checker_3
Reading symbols from ./license_checker_3...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) b * main+0xa0
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1219
(gdb) r 9191919191
Starting program: /mnt/c/Users/sverma/Desktop/tmp/license_checker_3 9191919191

Breakpoint 1, 0x0000555555555219 in main ()
(gdb) x/xi $rip
=> 0x555555555219 <main+160>:   cmpl   $0x32,-0x10(%rbp)
(gdb) x/dw $rbp-0x10
0x7fffffffe0b0: 60
```